# Not Sure How to Use HTML Helper for Collections in My ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to leverage HTML helpers for collections that I'm looping through, but I'm not sure how to do that.  More specifically, in the code below I'm trying to create HTML helpers (Html.EditorFor) for modulegroup.Name and modulegroup.HtmlDivId.  How can this be done?

```
    @foreach (var modulegroup in Model.SelectedPage.ModuleGroupCollection)
    {
        <div>
            @modulegroup.Name
        </div>
        <div>
            @modulegroup.HtmlDivId
        </div>
        foreach (var module in modulegroup.ModuleCollection)
         {
            <div>
                @module.Name
            </div>
            <div>
                @if(module.LockedBy !=  null) { 
                 @module.LockedBy.Name   
                }
            </div>
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
int modulegroupIndex = 0;
int moduleIndex = 0;
}
@foreach (var modulegroup in Model.SelectedPage.ModuleGroupCollection)
{
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedPage.ModuleGroupCollection[modulegroupIndex].Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedPage.ModuleGroupCollection[modulegroupIndex].HtmlDivId)
    </div>
    foreach (var module in modulegroup.ModuleCollection)
     {
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedPage.ModuleGroupCollection[modulegroupIndex].ModuleCollection[moduleIndex].Name)
        </div>
        <div>
            @if(module.LockedBy !=  null) { 
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedPage.ModuleGroupCollection[modulegroupIndex].ModuleCollection[moduleIndex].LockedBy.Name) 
            }
        </div>
        moduleIndex++;
     }
     modulegroupIndex++;
}
```

Comment: My collections are actually ICollections so I can't refer to them via their index.  Is there another way to use HtmlHelpers for a different model other than the base model?

Comment: @ZacEmmel - Sorry, this is the only method I am aware of. Perhaps you could use IEnumerable? I know it exposes a few more members than ICollection but it will allow the use of these helpers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for EditorTemplates vs HTML Helpers. Here is some reading on the subject: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

I generally place view specific templates within a sub folder "EditorTemplates" of the view folder they relate to. For reusable templates I would do the same but simply but the "EditorTemplates" folder within the shared folder.

That said, here is an example that will simplify your view somewhat given the following sample model & controller. Note, this will output the following:

```
first
one
collection1
jonah jameson
collection2
spidey
```

*Controller*:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SampleViewModel
                    {
                        SomeGroup = new List<ModuleGroupCollection>
                                        {
                                            new ModuleGroupCollection
                                                {
                                                    HtmlDivId = "one",
                                                    Name = "first",
                                                    SomeCollection = new List<ModuleCollection>
                                                                            {
                                                                                new ModuleCollection()
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        Name = "collection1",
                                                                                        LockedBy = "jonah jameson"
                                                                                    },
                                                                                new ModuleCollection()
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        Name = "collection2",
                                                                                        LockedBy = "spidey"
                                                                                    }
                                                                            }


                                                }
                                        }

                    };

    return View("Index", model);
}
```

*Model*:

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ModuleGroupCollection> SomeGroup { get; set; }
}

public class ModuleGroupCollection
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HtmlDivId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ModuleCollection> SomeCollection { get; set; }
}

public class ModuleCollection
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LockedBy { get; set; }
}
```

*The View, note the usage of the editor templates*:

```
@model StackQuestions.Models.SampleViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.SomeGroup) {
     @Html.EditorFor(x=>item)
     foreach (var module in item.SomeCollection)
     {
         @Html.EditorFor(x=>module)
     }
}
```

Module Collection Editor Template:

```
@model StackQuestions.Models.ModuleCollection
<div>
   @Model.Name
</div>
<div>
    @if (Model.LockedBy != null)
    { 
        @Model.LockedBy   
    }
</div>
```

Module Group Collection Editor Template:

```
@model StackQuestions.Models.ModuleGroupCollection
<div>
    @Model.Name
</div>
<div>
    @Model.HtmlDivId
</div>
```